# No sound in Ubuntu 13.04 i386

Tags: ubuntu

I have a machine running Windows 7-ultimate 32-bit. I installed vmware workstation on it and Ubuntu 13.04 i386 on that vmware. But on Ubuntu I don't hear any sound, any start up or movie or music sound. I have installed other OSes on that vmware but no one has that sound problem.

Comment: No one know!!??

Comment: To get sound working in VMWARE see my notes [here][1].

  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/679277/sound-not-working-in-vmware-player/849075#849075